# Make one section of simple web page have own scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I have a section of the web page I am building that is dedicated to news events.  These are simply entered as follows currently.

```
<tr>
    <td class="newsdate">
        February 2013
    </td>
    <td class="news">
        News item 1
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="newsdate">
        January 2013
    </td>
    <td class="news">
        News items 2
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to have it so that when there are more than 5 events listed, say, then you can use a scroll bar to see old events.  That is the height of the news section will be fixed but you can scroll up and down within it to see newer and older news.  How can you do this most simply?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a div vertically scrollable using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707397/making-a-div-vertically-scrollable-using-css)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Wrap your `table` in a `div` using `overflow-y: auto;` like this

HTML

```
<div class="scrollable">
    <!-- Your table -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scrollable {
    height: 100px; /* or any value */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS:

```
.scrollbar {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto; // here is the magic :)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML example markup:

```
  <ul id="container">
    <li>Article 1</li>
    <li>Article 2</li>
    <li>Article 3</li>
    <li>Article 4</li>
    <li>Article 5</li>
    <li>Article 6</li>
    <li>Article 7</li>
    <li>Article 8</li>
  </ul>
```

and CSS:

```
ul#container {
    height: 100px; 
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UvsrY/4/

Answer (score 1):

If your news events are wrapped in a `<table id="news">`, then your CSS would look like this:

```
#news {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your table inside a DIV element and specify a height, like this:

```
<div style="height:400px;overflow:auto">
   <table>....</table>
</div>
```

It will be automatically scrolled if needed

Comment: I can't recommend using the `style` attribute

Comment: I believe we should avoid using inline CSS in our HTML code as much as posible.

Comment: I think using inline `style` attributes are fine in certain cases.  If this is a unique style, it makes the HTML easier to read by keeping it attached to the `<div>` tag.  The alternative is to create an arbitrary class name and define it in a `<style>` section or in an ever-growing `.css` file; both require hunting it down to make changes.  On the other hand, if this style is used anywhere else then the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself) applies and you should use a class name.