# Make just one section scrollable, not the entire page

Tags: css, html, overflow

I am working on a project in which one of the sections is filled with elements by requesting data from the database, therefore the number of elements in it is extremely variable.

The tricky part is that our design is based on the idea of not having to scroll on the page, but instead scroll on the sections if it is necessary. I thought using `overflow` on the sections would suffice but it does not give me the intended result.

I tried all of the variations of the `overflow` property, `scroll` displays a scroll bar but it seems to be frozen.

How can I make `section-one` scrollable within itself, without making the rest of the page scrollable?

I created a code pen with a dummy version to demonstrate the problem: http://codepen.io/leofontes/pen/aNaBox

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.section-one {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  float: left;
  min-height: 1400px;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 15%;
}

.section-two {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  float: left;
  min-height: 1400px;
  width: 70%;
}

.section-three {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  min-height: 1400px;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="section-one">
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
  </section>
  <section class="section-two">
    <p>this is section two</p>
  </section>
  <section class="section-three">
    <p>this is section three</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Thank you

Comment: I think the solution to your problem already has been posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380442/make-one-section-of-simple-web-page-have-own-scroll-bar)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make these adjustments to your CSS:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;                       /* note #1 */
}
body {
  height: 100%;                       /* note #1 */
  margin: 0;                          /* note #2 */
  overflow: hidden;
}
main {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.section-one {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;                  /* new */
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;                      /* note #3 */
}
.section-two {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  float: left;
  min-height: 1400px;
  width: 70%;
}
.section-three {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  min-height: 1400px;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="section-one">
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
    <p>this is section one</p>
  </section>
  <section class="section-two">
    <p>this is section two</p>
  </section>
  <section class="section-three">
    <p>this is section three</p>
  </section>

</main>
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNdbzm)

Notes:

1. [When using percentage heights, parent elements must have a specified height.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
2. [Remove the default margin from the `body` element.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36219088/3597276)
3. Adding a `height` to the element causes the `overflow` to work.

Comment: Thank you very much, not only solved my problem the answer made sense and helped me understand what was going on.

Comment: is it possible to make section-two scrollable, but prevent it from scrolling when section-one is scrolled.