# How to scroll in a div?

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll

I've got a div the images in it. There are going to be a lot of images so I want to be able to scroll down within the div. How do I do that?

Thanks :)

HTML:

```
<div id="TextureView">
    <div id="TextureViewInside">
        <ul class="products">
             <img src="FärgadePapper.png">
             <img src="Hajar.png">
             <img src="Labyrint.png">
             <img src="Martini.png">
             <img src="FärgadePapper.png">
             <img src="Hajar.png">
             <img src="Labyrint.png">
             <img src="Martini.png">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#TextureView{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#TextureViewInside{
    padding: 7px;
}
ul.products img{
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

My JavaScript is empty so there is no point showing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a div vertically scrollable using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707397/making-a-div-vertically-scrollable-using-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following code:

```
#TextureView { 
  height: 450px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

You'll have a scroll once the images exceed the height of the container, otherwise - the scroller won't appear.

Comment: In addition, if you want to support physics-based accelerated scrolling on iPhone, add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`.

Answer (score 2):

```
overflow:scroll;
```

should work for this purpose

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

will create scroll bar horizontally, if you want to scroll content from left to right ( or vice verse )

```
overflow-x:scroll;
```

will create scroll bar vertically

Comment: It would be ideal to explain `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` also

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the overflow to be scroll:

```
#TextureView { overflow: scroll; height: 400px; }
```

This will cause a scroll bar to appear once the inside exceeds the height specified (it doesn't have to be `400px`). Alternately you can say just `overflow-y` to get a only vertical scroll bar.

Comment: It will show a disabled scrollbar if the images didn't exceed the height of the container.

Answer (score 1):

```
#TextureView{ 
overflow-y:scroll;
height:500px;
}
```

modify your css and keep div's height as per your need

Answer (score 0):

Changing your CSS to something like this:

```
#TextureView{
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px;
}
```

would work.   `overflow: scroll;` allows the scrollbar to appear.   Setting the `height` keeps the DIV from expanding automatically.

I've created a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfsamet/w5yYF/)** here to show how it would look with content above, content below, and a scrollable DIV.