# Make div scrollable

Tags: css, html

I have a div that I am displaying many things in that are related to laptop for filtering data. The div increases it's size as the data size increases in it.

I want the div to remain at a max size of 450px then if data increases scroll will come automatically. The div size should not be increased.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/7w8TC/) for it.

css :

```
.itemconfiguration
{
    min-height:440px;
    width:215px;
    /* background-color:#CCC; */        
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:-5px;
}

.left_contentlist
{
    width:215px;
    float:left;
    padding:0 0 0 5px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    border-right: 1px #f8f7f3 solid;
    /* background-image:url(images/bubble.png); */
    /* background-color: black; */
}
```

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: set a fixed width then add `overflow-y:scroll` to that div:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a div vertically scrollable using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707397/making-a-div-vertically-scrollable-using-css)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use `overflow-y:auto` for displaying scroll automatically when the content exceeds the divs set height.

### [See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7w8TC/1/)

Comment: And I want to place button at the end of div if data exist or not ? what to do for that ?

Comment: @user3145373 can you tell in detail what you want

Comment: Sir data listed of configuration in that div and at the end filter button is there, so I want that if there is data or not in that div but the button should always at bottom of the div. Suppose there's only 2 data like RAM and processor so button will come very upside, I want that button will remain at bottom of the div at last if there's no data there.

Comment: @user3145373 i will post a fiddle later today.Do check for it

Comment: If I got correctly what you are asking then this may help you http://jsfiddle.net/7w8TC/4/ .In this fiddle i have wrapped the part inside form excluding submit button with a div whose **min-height is 100%**. So the container will push the submit button to the bottom even if the list is empty/or less items

Comment: Yes that's I want, thanx.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an older question and that the original question needed the `div` to have a fixed `height`, but I thought I would share that this can also be accomplished without a fixed pixel `height` for those looking for that kind of answer.

What I mean is that you can use something like:

```
.itemconfiguration
{
    // ...style rules...
    height: 25%; //or whatever percentage is needed
    overflow-y: scroll;
    // ...maybe more style rules...
}
```

This method works better for fluid layouts that need to adapt to the height of the screen they are being viewed on and also works for the `overflow-x` property.

---

I also thought it would be worth mentioning the differences in the values for the `overflow` style property as I've seen some people using `auto` and others using `scroll`:

**visible** = The overflowing content is not clipped and will make the `div` larger than the set `height`.

**hidden** = The overflowing content is clipped, and the rest of the content that is outside the set `height` of the `div` will be invisible

**scroll** = The overflowing content is clipped, but a scroll-bar is added to see the rest of the content within the set `height` of the `div`

**auto** = If there is overflowing content, it is clipped and a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content within the set `height` of the `div`

See also on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for more information and examples.

Comment: Yes, thanks for posting an answer. thanks for sharing.

Comment: actually this is wrong. i have  divs set to hidden and it stretches vertically beyond belief. in fact i actually need it to not stretch and give me a vertical scroll bar but there is no setting that will allow it. ppl are using java and all kinds of things to accomplish it. its amazing that something so simple is so "hard" to accomplish. im assuming it has something to do with the div being wrapped and the browsers ignoring certain settings

Answer (score 16):

use **`overflow:auto`** property, If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content,and mention the **height**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/5Ekdu/)**

```
 .itemconfiguration
    {
        height: 440px;
        width: 215px;
        overflow: auto;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: -5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the

```
min-height:440px;
```

to

```
height:440px;
```

and then add

```
overflow: auto;
```

property to the class of the required div

Comment: And I want to place button at the end of div if data exist or not ? what to do for that ?

Comment: @user3145373 do you want this functionality [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/7w8TC/3/)-----

Answer (score 5):

Place this into your DIV style

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Answer (score 5):

To further clarify, you can use `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto`. They'll both work!

"The **auto** value is similar to **scroll**, but it adds scrollbars only when necessary" ([source](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp#:%7E:text=overflow%3A%20auto,content%20overflows%20an%20element%27s%20box.))

You can also further specify which direction you want to control overflow in, and which direction you want the scrollbar to appear by doing `overflow-y: scroll` (top/bottom) or `overflow-x: scroll` (left/right). If you use the generic `overflow` property, it will overflow in both x and y directions if needed.

"You can use the **overflow** property when you want better control of the layout. The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box." ([source](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp#:%7E:text=overflow%3A%20auto,content%20overflows%20an%20element%27s%20box.))

Answer (score 1):

use css `overflow:scroll;` property. you need to specify height and width then you will be able to scroll horizontally and vertically or either one of two scroll by setting `overflow-x:auto;` or `overflow-y:auto;`

Answer (score 1):

You should add overflow property like following:

```
.itemconfiguration
    {   
        height: 300px; 
        overflow-y:auto;
        width:215px;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        margin-left:-5px;
    }
```

Comment: And I want to place button at the end of div if data exist or not ? what to do for that ?

Comment: @user3145373 you can place button at the end of the div.Are you asking about how to place button ? or are you asking about how to check whether your data exits in div or not. Your question is not clear.

Comment: yes I am talking about to place button at the bottom of the div.

Comment: @user3145373 `<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>` . You can place button where you want in div.

Comment: no no no, in fiddle check filter button is there, I want to place at end of div whether list data exist or not in that.

Comment: @user3145373 how are you binding data ? Are you hard coding ? You can check this at button onClick event through javascript or jQuery