# Bootstrap scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a div that is always the height of the screen, even if it has more content in it. The div shows a list of , and if there are more than can be contained in the screen there will be a scrollbar on the side of the div.

```
<div class = "Row">
   <div class ="col-sm-2">
       <ul>
           <li>
               <h1>record1</h1>
           </li>
           <li>
               <h1>record2</h1>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've searched online but only found answers that have nothing to do with my issue, like scrollable modals and other scroll issues. Please explain your answer **fully** with steps and full code.

Comment: Maybe you've searched online using the wrong keywords?

Comment: I specifically added that last line because people answer in one word, assuming that I know what they mean.

Comment: @Then I don't know the right keywords. I've tried every combonation I could think of and didn't find anything.

Comment: @rosa you could have taken a look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609531/how-can-i-make-a-div-100-of-window-height) and then here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227287/make-div-scrollable) very basic search keywords on stackoverflow

Comment: @ I can't use 100% or 100vh because I need it to fit the size of the screen, even after resize

Comment: Just use `max-height: 100vh; height: 100%;`

Comment: @rosa `I can't use 100% or 100vh because I need it to fit the size of the screen` - That's a pretty contradictory sentence.

Comment: Working example using vh and % : https://jsfiddle.net/Laa87pkw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web page's `body` is by default only as high as the content one put into it, so we need to tell it to be full viewport height (the size of the browser window)

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Now, for your `row` `div` to also be full height, we give that to a height

```
.row {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And finally, for the scroll bar to appear when the content exceed the height, we add

```
.row {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

The `background: #eee;` I just added so you see that covers the whole browser window

The `height: 100%` will now make the `row` `div` to automatically fill up the entire viewport (browser window) no matter size or if one resize it.

Sample code snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.row {
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class = "row">
   <div class ="col-sm-2">
       <ul>
           <li>
               <h1>record1</h1>
           </li>
           <li>
               <h1>record2</h1>
           </li>
           <li>
               <h1>record3</h1>
           </li>
           <li>
               <h1>record4</h1>
           </li>
           <li>
               <h1>record5</h1>
           </li>
           <li>
               <h1>record6</h1>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use height: 100% because row doesn't have a fixed height. I need row to be the height of the screen automatically.

Comment: @rosa It is exactly what `100%` do, make it `100%` of the browser window.