# Listable select menu dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello everyone I have a select menu dropdown, but there are a lot of elements and I would like to make it scrollable. How can this be done?

For example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbYj3.png)

Comment: [How to Make a Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a fixed height, something like `height: 500px`, then set `overflow-y: scroll`. You can also use `auto` if you would like the scrollbar to hide when the content inside of the menu div does not exceed the height of the div.

```css
.scrollable_dropdown {
  height: 500px;
  /* This can also be auto */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30379387/21677455 for more information about possible options.