# Scrollable nested table in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have some troubles when creating scrollable table in HTML.

From some similar question in Stackoverflow, using `overflow: auto` in `CSS` is workable, but I can't implement successfully

Is there anyone who can help to check is there anything wrong in my code?

I'd like to make left red cell scrollable only.

```
#samples {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Full code is in: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNj9m/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS to the `<table id="samples">`

```
style="height:200px; overflow:auto;display:block;"
```

Or in the CSS file

```
#samples {
   overflow: auto;
   height: 200px;
   display:block;
}
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNj9m/3/)

---

**EDIT**

This may not be what you want to hear, but `display: table-cell` does not respect width and will be collapsed based on the width of the entire table. You can get around this easily just by having a `display: block` element inside of the table cell itself whose width you specify

I've messed a little with the CSS in order to center the elements.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNj9m/6/)

Comment: Do you know why I can't rearrange the width in the `#samples`?

Comment: can you help to check my update code: http://jsfiddle.net/LNj9m/7/ . I extract the scrollable part and I can't re-arrange the width of left side column. Thank you.

Comment: @Jimmy Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/k25ak/

Comment: Nope. Can two `sample_path_01` placed parallel ? Like http://jsfiddle.net/k25ak/1/ but should be wilder.

Comment: @Jimmy Yes they can, I changed the display to inline-block on the th element: http://jsfiddle.net/k25ak/2/

Comment: I didn't get it. Can I specify a number for the width? ex 70% for 1st `th` and 30% for 2nd. http://jsfiddle.net/k25ak/3/

Comment: add partial codd using `nth-child` http://jsfiddle.net/k25ak/3/

Comment: @Jimmy Try 70% and 29%

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47968/discussion-between-filip-huysmans-and-jimmy)

Comment: I can't make `samples` as wilder as it's parent table.

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be to put the table inside a div and make the div scrollable?

See this post -

[Making a div vertically scrollable using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707397/making-a-div-vertically-scrollable-using-css)

Hope this helps.