# Changing message displays to bottom to top

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am doing a social network service using asp.net/c#, I have little problems with message sending. Message are flowed top to bottom. [Like this](https://scontent-b-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/14034_1507005402922369_2076207787010101354_n.jpg?oh=996a4172ad592890e7966e3dfb3dcaa5&oe=553B7068)

But I want to display messages [bottom to top Like facebook](https://scontent-b-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10646971_1507007459588830_3703185016176137413_n.jpg?oh=82b2a00558f316cd434051674a3cdcea&oe=55411FD5)..

I am displaying messages using repeater control.

repeater control code

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
 <ItemTemplate>     
     <div style="border-top: thin none #BBCEB3; border-bottom: thin none #BBCEB3; padding: 10px;  width: 548px; margin-top: 10px; right: 10px; left: 10px; border-left-width: thin; margin-left: 15px; background-color: #e9eaee; border-left-color: #BBCEB3; border-right-color: #BBCEB3;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <div style="width: 58px; height: 40px">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="59px" ImageAlign="Top" ImageUrl="~/Profile/Image/Default.png" Width="55px" />
                        </div>
                    <div style="width: 307px;  margin-left: 65px; margin-top: -60px">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="#000066"><%#Eval("SenderID") %> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="status" style=" width: 461px; margin-left: 78px; margin-top: 11px;">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Font-Italic="False" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="Medium"><%#Eval("Messages") %> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;<div style="margin-left: 350px">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server"  Text="Posted on: " Font-Size="Small"><%#Eval("Time") %> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>

 </ItemTemplate>
```

Textbox code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Message" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox3_TextChanged" style="margin-left: 12px; text-align: left;" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="564px" Height="100px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of Items in the repeater will be the same as in DataSource, so just Order it by Time descending before bind.

Comment: you are correct.it's works, now tell me How to create a scrollable Div Tag Vertically?

Comment: @SoftwaresAŋɖTricks look at the stack overflow's question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707397/making-a-div-vertically-scrollable-using-css

Comment: i did it also, and i have another problem, when i refresh it, it shows first message that i sent(therefore it scorlls to top when page is loading). but i want to show last message i sent when it page refresh.could you tell me how to do it? I think i need a load more older message function to stop that, but i don't know how to do it?

Comment: @SoftwaresAŋɖTricks your requirements is not so clear, however if you want bring some dynamic (live) actions like autoscroll or fetching data without users actions (e.g. by timer) you should look at what JavaSript can do for you

Comment: when i am starting to send message scroll display [like this](https://scontent-b-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10906209_1507241386232104_79420700166337212_n.jpg?oh=bd971f020987357dcca17c94ac707564&oe=5536BC0B). when i press send message it shows old message [first and scroll is top](https://scontent-b-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10898054_1507241806232062_2461530347045754305_n.jpg?oh=44a103a5524a94e358275da237ab1d74&oe=55297972), but i want newer message

Comment: Div scrolls to top because of component/page is reloaded by browser, and for browser this is new content/page, to bring the context to the browser side at this point you could use JavaScript (e.g. $().scrollTo) to handle position of scroll on the page when page is ready (e.g. $(document).ready event)

Comment: actually i don't have big knowledge about javascript. could you can give me any code for that

Comment: It would be better to use search on StackOverflow or google.com

Comment: friend. can you edit this code by adding ajax, what should i do to add ajax, i didn't use ajax yet for this social network

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67931/discussion-between-softwares-a-tricks-and-victor).