# Angular Material : How to make content scrollable

Tags: html, angular-material

I am using angular material and want to design a layout for my application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Angular Material - Starter App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.8.3/angular-material.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"/>

</head>

<body ng-app="starterApp" layout="column" layout-fill>

    <div flex="30" style="border: 1px solid darkgrey;background-color: #1CA9F0;"></div>
    <div flex style="border: 1px solid firebrick;" layout="column">
        <div flex="5" layout="row" layout-align="center">
            <md-toolbar flex="50">
                <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
                    <span>Toolbar</span>
                </h2>
            </md-toolbar>
        </div>
        <div flex layout="row" layout-align="center">
            <md-content flex="50">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne quod novum mei. Sea omnium invenire mediocrem at, in lobortis conclusionemque nam. Ne deleniti appetere reprimique pro, inani labitur disputationi te sed. At vix sale omnesque, id pro labitur reformidans accommodare, cum labores honestatis eu. Nec quem lucilius in, eam praesent reformidans no. Sed laudem aliquam ne.
                <p>
                    Facete delenit argumentum cum at. Pro rebum nostrum contentiones ad. Mel exerci tritani maiorum at, mea te audire phaedrum, mel et nibh aliquam. Malis causae equidem vel eu. Noster melius vis ea, duis alterum oporteat ea sea. Per cu vide munere fierent.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Ad sea dolor accusata consequuntur. Sit facete convenire reprehendunt et. Usu cu nonumy dissentiet, mei choro omnes fuisset ad. Te qui docendi accusam efficiantur, doming noster prodesset eam ei. In vel posse movet, ut convenire referrentur eum, ceteros singulis intellegam eu sit.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Sit saepe quaestio reprimique id, duo no congue nominati, cum id nobis facilisi. No est laoreet dissentias, idque consectetuer eam id. Clita possim assueverit cu his, solum virtute recteque et cum. Vel cu luptatum signiferumque, mel eu brute nostro senserit. Blandit euripidis consequat ex mei, atqui torquatos id cum, meliore luptatum ut usu. Cu zril perpetua gubergren pri. Accusamus rationibus instructior ei pro, eu nullam principes qui, reque justo omnes et quo.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Sint unum eam id. At sit fastidii theophrastus, mutat senserit repudiare et has. Atqui appareat repudiare ad nam, et ius alii incorrupte. Alii nullam libris his ei, meis aeterno at eum. Ne aeque tincidunt duo. In audire malorum mel, tamquam efficiantur has te.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Qui utamur tacimates quaestio ad, quod graece omnium ius ut. Pri ut vero debitis interpretaris, qui cu mentitum adipiscing disputationi. Voluptatum mediocritatem quo ut. Fabulas dolorem ei has, quem molestie persequeris et sit.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Est in vivendum comprehensam conclusionemque, alia cetero iriure no usu, te cibo deterruisset pro. Ludus epicurei quo id, ex cum iudicabit intellegebat. Ex modo deseruisse quo, mel noster menandri sententiae ea, duo et tritani malorum recteque. Nullam suscipit partiendo nec id, indoctum vulputate per ex. Et has enim habemus tibique. Cu latine electram cum, ridens propriae intellegat eu mea.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Duo at aliquid mnesarchum, nec ne impetus hendrerit. Ius id aeterno debitis atomorum, et sed feugait voluptua, brute tibique no vix. Eos modo esse ex, ei omittam imperdiet pro. Vel assum albucius incorrupte no. Vim viris prompta repudiare ne, vel ut viderer scripserit, dicant appetere argumentum mel ea. Eripuit feugait tincidunt pri ne, cu facilisi molestiae usu.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Qui utamur tacimates quaestio ad, quod graece omnium ius ut. Pri ut vero debitis interpretaris, qui cu mentitum adipiscing disputationi. Voluptatum mediocritatem quo ut. Fabulas dolorem ei has, quem molestie persequeris et sit.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Est in vivendum comprehensam conclusionemque, alia cetero iriure no usu, te cibo deterruisset pro. Ludus epicurei quo id, ex cum iudicabit intellegebat. Ex modo deseruisse quo, mel noster menandri sententiae ea, duo et tritani malorum recteque. Nullam suscipit partiendo nec id, indoctum vulputate per ex. Et has enim habemus tibique. Cu latine electram cum, ridens propriae intellegat eu mea.
                </p>

            </md-content>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div flex="5" style="border: 1px solid turquoise;"></div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.8.3/angular-material.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        angular
                .module('starterApp', ['ngMaterial'])
                .run(function ($log) {
                    $log.debug("starterApp + ngMaterial running...");
                });

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

My question is, how to make the md-content scrollable? The div on the bottom should be a sticky footer. Attention, on chrome looks works but on firefox not. I am trust firefox, because chrome has issue with flexbox.

I've created a plunker, but I can't insert link into the thread, it appears always an error msg.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This problem no longer appears with Angular-Material 1.1.1 - the original question was at the time of version 0.8.3

**ORIGINAL**

Use md-content on the outer elements as well.

```
<body ng-app="starterApp" layout="column" layout-fill>

  <div flex="30" style="border: 1px solid darkgrey;background-color: #1CA9F0;"></div>
  <md-content flex style="border: 1px solid firebrick;" layout="column">
      <div flex="5" layout="row" layout-align="center">
          <md-toolbar flex="50">
              <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
                  <span>Toolbar</span>
              </h2>
          </md-toolbar>
      </div>
      <md-content flex layout="row" layout-align="center">
          <md-content flex="50">
            ...
          </md-content>
      </md-content>
  </md-content>
  <div flex="5" style="border: 1px solid turquoise;"></div>
  ...
</body>
```

[Plunkr] http://plnkr.co/edit/IfEtX638z4ymccC0Ua53?p=preview

See: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1906

Comment: I know, but it has worked well so far. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: So [if this](https://plnkr.co/edit/8MpYrHBQIkHvIrSNHApw?p=preview) is a correct plunker of the OP's question, it appears to behave identically; is it because this is a bug, which was fixed? [I think so...](https://github.com/bderenzi/bderenzi-www/commit/c61bb181ffe88d7159aac3112728855136b87d7a)

Comment: This is an old question, there have been several fixes regarding this problem over the past 2 years.

Answer (score 7):

try adding `style="overflow: scroll;"` to the tag you wish to be scrollable.

For example I have in mine:

```
<div layout="column" flex style="overflow: scroll;">
    <div id="content" ng-view flex></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not enough to set `overflow: scroll`.

You need to add `position: absolute` and to set a size of your container that need to be scrollable. Try something like this:

```
md-content{
     position: absolute;
     height: 100px;
}
```

For more information of scrolling containers read [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9707674)

Thanks.

Comment: Almost works, but this obviously limits your scroll height to 100 pixels. To make it work on any screen use **height: calc(100vh - 10px);** instead.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem (angular material 0.11.0)

index.html

```html
<body ng-app="app" layout="column" >
    <div flex layout="column" ng-include="'app/layout/shell.html'" ></div>
 <body>
```

shell.html

```html
<div layout="row" flex style="overflow: hidden;" ng-controller="Shell" layout-fill>
    <div ng-include="'app/layout/left-side-nav.html'"></div>
    <md-content flex layout="column" role="main"  class="fondo" style="height: inherit">
        <div ng-include="'app/layout/app-toolbar.html'"></div>
        <md-content flex  style="background-color: transparent; flex-direction: column;" ng-hide="dataLoading.init">
            <div   ui-view     style="background-color: transparent"></div>
        </md-content>
    </md-content>
    <div ng-include="'app/layout/right-side-nav.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was as follows.
An **easy way** is,

```
<div style="left:0;
            top: 0;
            overflow: auto; 
            min-height:auto;
            max-height:100%;
            height:300px;">
```

Or add it as external css.

The trick is of overflow. If the data on page overflows, it will automatically become scrollable.

Also it will only make the data scrollable that will be in the div as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

To make the md-content scrollable, add the md-scroll-y attribute, like this:

```
<md-content md-scroll-y>
</md-content>
```