# Angular Material nested layouts breaks md-content scrolling

Tags: flexbox, angular-material

I would like to make a layout with a toolbar fixed on top, with two side-by-side content scrollable sections on the bottom.

I can correctly create this layout when the `md-content`s are only nested under one `div`.

Example ([CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZEjdP)):

```html
<body ng-app="app" layout="column">
  <md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-z4">Toolbar</md-toolbar>

  <div layout="column" flex>
    <md-content layout flex>
      <md-content flex="50" layout="column">
      <md-content flex="50" layout="column">
```

However, if I nested `md-content` under two or more `div`s this breaks the layout and causes the content to overflow out and causes the entire page to be scrollable.

Example ([CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrxLox)):

```html
<body ng-app="app" layout="column">
  <md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-z4">Toolbar</md-toolbar>

  <div layout="column" flex>
    <div layout="column" flex>
      <md-content layout flex>
        <md-content flex="50" layout="column">
        <md-content flex="50" layout="column">
```

What's going on? How can I create a scrollable `md-content` when it is inside a nested layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of https://stackoverflow.com/a/29516060/2553215.
Just use `md-content` instead of `div` on the outer elements as well.

http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/EPQeZd