# How to make two DIVs inside the main DIV fixed and scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, css-position

I have a situation where I have 3 `div`s:

```
<div id="div1"> // code 
    <div id="div2"> // code </div>
    <div id="div3"> // code </div>
</div>
```

I need to make it that `div1` is always the height of the browser window (responds to `window.resize`) and that the `div2` and `div3`  all have fixed locations in the browser (`div2` at the bottom of `div1` and `div3` in the middle of `div1` with a fixed `max-height`). Also, `div3` might have more content than can fit into its fixed height, so it has a scroll to look through all this content.

I tried various settings including `position: fixed;` and `top: 0; bottom: 0;` but it didn't work, as in my `div2` is always pushed beyond the boundary of the browser window.

Do you know how I could do that?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: can you offer a fiddle for this with the css you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9707674/4028085

Answer (score 0):

Try this to make the div scrollable:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
```

Code taken from this question and answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9707674/4028085)

Comment: yes, i can do scrollable, but how to make its location fixed and for it to not be positioned beyond the boundary of the browser window (and `div1`)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `overflow:scroll`?

CSS:

```css
#div3 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: yes, i can do scrollable, but how to make its location fixed and for it to not be positioned beyond the boundary of the browser window (and `div1`)?