# How can i put Scroll in a specific<div>

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to put a horizontal scroll in my page or in a specific .

I have a normal page in primefaces, and i need to put the  in a horizontal way, how can i put the scroll in this specific div that contain the forms ?

edit1 :

```html
    <div class="col-md-1" style="overflow-x:scroll; width:2000px">
      <div class="row">
        <p:fieldset>
          <campo:simples label="Data Referencia" />
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="row">
              <campo:radio enumClass="TipoTituloEnum" label="Situação" tamanho="1" tamanhoTotal="1" columns="1" layout="grid">
              </campo:radio>
            </div>
          </div>
        </p:fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I try this ^^ but the scroll didn't appear
Edit2: The scroll appear, but disabled

[Look ^^ the component overflow the screen but the scroll didn't appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkeiH.png)

Comment: The scroll appear but disabled

Comment: content of the div is not wider than 2000px. that is why the scrollbar looks disabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a div vertically scrollable using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707397/making-a-div-vertically-scrollable-using-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `overflow-x:auto` will do the trick

```css
 .col-md-1{
    overflow-x:scroll;
 }
 //If you don't want disabled scroll bar 
 .col-md-1{
    overflow-x:auto;
 }
```

Comment: And if you don't want a disabled scrollbar to show up when the content is not wide enough, go with `overflow-x:auto;` instead.

Comment: The scroll appear, but disabled

Comment: as @modu said if you don't want scroll to be visible as disabled use `overflow-x:auto` this will show scroll only when content of the div will go outside (overflow) the div.

Comment: Many duplicates... https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+html+css+scroll. Finding one and marking this as one is appreciated...