# how to scroll down inside div with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a div element that I want to scroll down inside it with selenium.
I want to scroll specific pixels.
What is the easiest way to do it?
I searched on web but didn't find fine explanation.

Comment: Is this div inside a nested window ? How does it look like ? Can you share html code or page url ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707397/making-a-div-vertically-scrollable-using-css

like the div here

Comment: There are multiple ways to scroll, actions class, java script executor, did you try any one of them ?

Comment: There is an option in actions class to scroll by pixels?
I tried the answer Prophet answered here but it throes exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
public void scrollOnElement(String cssSelector){
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    String script = String.format("document.querySelector('%s').scrollTop= 450",cssSelector);
    js.executeScript(script);
}
```

The css parameter here is the css selector locating the div element you want to scroll inside.
I use 450 pixels scrolling here however you can use any parameter instead.

Comment: what is the function stringFormat

Comment: Sorry. It's some helper method I use internally. Updated the answer

Comment: it throwing me exception "javascript error: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong method. Please see the updated answer

Comment: Yet, throwing the same exception. :(

Comment: I  use it in my code and it works perfect! Did you copied all the method as it appearing now?

Comment: I wrote in cssSelector "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='grid-canvas']"))"

Comment: This is not css selector! in this case the css selector is: `div.grid-canvas`