# How to stop flex element from growing over window

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey I am currently struggling with the following: I have `<div class="result-text">` that contains text. I want that the `<header>` and `<footer>` is always visible but if there is to much text in the div they disappear and I can scroll. This is not what I want.

The `<div>` should be scrollable.

The "main" scrollbar should not exists. The only thing which should be scrollable is the `<div>` that contains all the text. If i resize the window there must be always visible the header, sidebar and the footer. The `<div>` element with the text should always fill the remaining text.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #00ac17;
}

header {
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #004d20;
}

footer {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #49fa7e;
  color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
}

.sidebarleft {
  flex: 0 0 55px;
  background-color: blue;
}


.data {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: rgb(185, 46, 46);
}

.textcontent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(152, 43, 255);
}

.diagram {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(113, 1, 165);
}

.input-textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 100px;
}

.result-text {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button1 {
  flex: 0;
}

.button2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.button3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Layout</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header></header>
      <main>
        <div class="sidebarleft"></div>
        <div class="data">
          <div class="textcontent">
            <textarea class="input-textarea"></textarea>
            <button class="button1">button1</button>
            <div class="result-text">
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text .
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="diagram"></div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I made a fiddle that you can view that has all my code: https://jsfiddle.net/n3zyLgcb/4/

The following design should stay, also if I resize the entire window:
[image]

But if there is to much text it looks like this:(not the behavior I want)
[image]

I **do not want** the scrollbar on the far right:(changed my code like @Faizal_Hussain said. )
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707397/making-a-div-vertically-scrollable-using-css

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this is not answering my problem. I tried many different things but i could not get it to work properly.

Comment: Added a snippet of the code in the fiddle to the question - hope I did not mess up the visuals of that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because both the header and footer are in a static position, you can check the static position here , https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

The fix should be in such a way that the position of these headers and footers should not change when we scroll , to do this add position fixed,
like

```
header {
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #004d20;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  top : 0
}

footer {
height: 25px;
background-color: #49fa7e;
color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
position : fixed;
bottom : 0
width : 100%
}

main{
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes it a bit better but i don't want site scrolling. The only scrollable element should be the `<div>` element on the side.  In your version there is still site scrolling enabled and div scrolling disabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot Faizal. Its now working properly :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #00ac17;
}

header {
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #004d20;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}

footer {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #49fa7e;
  color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
}

.sidebarleft {
  flex: 0 0 55px;
  background-color: blue;
}


.data {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: rgb(185, 46, 46);
}

.textcontent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(152, 43, 255);
}

.diagram {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgb(113, 1, 165);
}

.input-textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 100px;
}

.result-text {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 20px;
  max-height:500px;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.button1 {
  flex: 0;
}

.button2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.button3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Layout</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>nk</header>
      <main>
        <div class="sidebarleft"></div>
        <div class="data">
          <div class="textcontent">
            <textarea class="input-textarea"></textarea>
            <button class="button1">button1</button>
            <div class="result-text">
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a
              lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here
              is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text .
              Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of text . Here is a lot of
              text .
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="diagram"></div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer>mkmk</footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not working how i want it. If i resize the window the layout should stay.  Also the `result-text` field should always fill out the entire space. This i s also not the case in your answer.

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer better.