# How to limit height of nested <pre> in flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am writing an electron app and the basic screen layout is a two-column flex with forms on the **top** and a code editor in the **bottom** underneath. These panes are resizing as expected using CSS flex.  I am having a problem though with content within the bottom pane.

When content is loaded, I would like the content block (in orange) below to remain within the bounds of its **bottom** parent and have scroll bars appear in that block.  What ends up happening is that the orange code element grows to accommodate the code, without the parent showing scroll bars.

I *can* get the entire bottom panel to scroll (green and red/orange), but I'd rather not do that unless I have to.

The HTML below demonstrates this (click on the "Toggle Code" button to load).

[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { overflow: hidden; }
        #container { display:flex; flex-direction: column; height:100vh; width:100vw; overflow: hidden; }
        #top { width:100%; flex-grow: 1; background-color: #E0E0FF }
        #bottom { display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-grow:2; margin-top: 24px; }
        #bottom-left { width:64px; background-color:#E0FFE0 }
        #bottom-right { display:flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 1; background-color: #FFE0E0; }
        #bottom-right-header { flex-grow: 0; }
        #bottom-right-content { flex-grow: 1; overflow:auto; background-color: orange;" }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let showing = false;
        function toggleCode() {
            let text = '';
            showing = !showing
            if(showing) {
                for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) text += `Line ${i}\n`;
            }
            document.getElementById('bottom-right-content').innerText = text;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="top">
            <h3>This content can vary in length...</h3>
            <div>Line 1</div>
            <div>Line 2</div>
            <div>Line 3</div>
            <div>Line 4</div>
            <div>Line 5</div>
            <div>Line 6</div>
            <div>Line 7</div>
            <div>Line 8</div>
            <div>Line 9</div>
            <div>Line 10</div>
            <div>Line 11</div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
            <div id="bottom-left">
                <div>[Btn 1]</div>
                <div>[Btn 2]</div>
                <div>[Btn 3]</div>
                <div>[Btn 4]</div>
                <div>[Btn 5]</div>
            </div>
            <div id="bottom-right">
                <div id="bottom-right-header">
                    I would like to restrict the orange block below to the parent div's height and show scroll bars...
                    <button onClick="toggleCode()">Toggle Code</button>
                </div>
                <pre id="bottom-right-content">
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707397/making-a-div-vertically-scrollable-using-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question can be flagged as a duplicate (see [Why don't flex items shrink past-content-size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size) ), I'll give the answer anyway, because it might not be obvious: `#bottom { min-height: 0; }`

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { overflow: hidden; }
        #container { display:flex; flex-direction: column; height:100vh; width:100vw; overflow: hidden; }
        #top { width:100%; flex-grow: 1; background-color: #E0E0FF }
        #bottom {
          display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-grow:2; margin-top: 24px;
          min-height: 0; /* <== */
         }
        #bottom-left { width:64px; background-color:#E0FFE0 }
        #bottom-right { display:flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 1; background-color: #FFE0E0; }
        #bottom-right-header { flex-grow: 0; }
        #bottom-right-content { flex-grow: 1; overflow:auto; background-color: orange;" }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let showing = false;
        function toggleCode() {
            let text = '';
            showing = !showing
            if(showing) {
                for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) text += `Line ${i}\n`;
            }
            document.getElementById('bottom-right-content').innerText = text;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="top">
            <h3>This content can vary in length...</h3>
            <div>Line 1</div>
            <div>Line 2</div>
            <div>Line 3</div>
            <div>Line 4</div>
            <div>Line 5</div>
            <div>Line 6</div>
            <div>Line 7</div>
            <div>Line 8</div>
            <div>Line 9</div>
            <div>Line 10</div>
            <div>Line 11</div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
            <div id="bottom-left">
                <div>[Btn 1]</div>
                <div>[Btn 2]</div>
                <div>[Btn 3]</div>
                <div>[Btn 4]</div>
                <div>[Btn 5]</div>
            </div>
            <div id="bottom-right">
                <div id="bottom-right-header">
                    I would like to restrict the orange block below to the parent div's height and show scroll bars...
                    <button onClick="toggleCode()">Toggle Code</button>
                </div>
                <pre id="bottom-right-content">
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!  First - setting bottom on the parent was the magic piece of this, and I gave you credit for the solve.  Second - I really did spend a bunch of time trying to search for the answer.  An appropriate permutation of the magic words "Why don't flex items shrink past content size" obviously didn't make their way to my brain.  I'm assuming you took mercy upon me because I took the time to document a working case, and I appreciate it.

Comment: I was glad to help!